# How to make background images change every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get images to change every 3 seconds using only Javascript. Here's what I came up with:

```
var imageArray = [
  "assets/background1.jpeg",
  "assets/background2.jpeg",
  "assets/background3.jpeg"
];

var imageIndex = 0; 

function changeImage() {
  imageArray.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % imageArray.length;
}

setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
```

Any ideas? Currently it doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the image on the `imageArray`

```
imageArray.setAttribute( "src", imageArray[imageIndex] );
```

but you should have to add `src` to `image` element

```
image.setAttribute( "src", imageArray[imageIndex] );
```

```js
const image = document.querySelector( "img" );
var imageArray = [
    "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/building-a-strong-team-wooden-blocks-with-people-icon-on-pink-human-picture-id1227412970?b=1&k=6&m=1227412970&s=170667a&w=0&h=2vUvq_9zUItF9UJuySkix_rZd53MM32W-QzZWwjq0zI=",
    "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/womens-hand-typing-on-mobile-smartphone-live-chat-chatting-on-web-picture-id1217093906?b=1&k=6&m=1217093906&s=170667a&w=0&h=57BAau-SLTJ2s7WjehjH9HaCeou5FMIgG0p00QW-YaE=",
    "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/partnership-of-business-concept-business-network-picture-id1223929743?b=1&k=6&m=1223929743&s=170667a&w=0&h=asL62WU1trQUqj_u0VpQJ56-FW88RE0sq5HhPMwthaQ="
];

// First time set the first image indexed at 0
image.setAttribute( "src", imageArray[0] )

var imageIndex = 1;
function changeImage() {
    console.log( `showing image #${imageIndex}` );
    image.setAttribute( "src", imageArray[imageIndex] );
    imageIndex = ( imageIndex + 1 ) % imageArray.length;
}

setInterval( changeImage, 5000 );
```

```html
<img src="" alt="" srcset="">
```

Comment: I see, I updated it. I'm still not getting anything displayed. I'm wondering if I need another var?

Comment: Working code also attached. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
imageArray.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex])
```

You must `setAttribute` for HTML element, not `imageArray`. You can see the below demo:

```js
var imageArray = [
  "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/floral-wedding-homepage-template_23-2149077924.jpg",
  "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/cartoon-podium-background-design-illustration_52683-70692.jpg",
  "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/farm-landscape-scene-with-barn-windmill_1308-58771.jpg"
];

// Move this variable to before the startChange and setInterval to let it have the value on the first time
var imageIndex = 0;

// Call on page load
startChange();

// Show first image and set interval
function startChange() {
  changeImage();
  setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
}

// Main function to get HTML element and set image into it
function changeImage() {
  document.getElementById('image').setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % imageArray.length;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the DOM element to set the attribute. You are doing it for the array which is invalid.

```js
var imageArray = ['https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/newscms/2021_22/3479356/210601-main-pups-canine-companions-for-independence-ew-113p.jpg', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0272/4770/6214/articles/when-do-puppies-start-walking.jpg?v=1593020034', 'https://dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/03/puppy-development.jpg']

var imgHolder = document.getElementById('images');
var imageIndex = 0;
function changeImage() {
   imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % imageArray.length;
   imgHolder.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex])
}

setInterval(changeImage, 3000);
```

```html
<img id="images" width=200 src="https://dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/03/puppy-development.jpg"></img>
```

Comment: Is your img tag for the HTML?

Comment: @Cpt_Gizmo yes it is

Comment: Answers with an explanation of how the code solves the problem are much more helpful.

Comment: Added explanation @Cully

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set the `src` on the image array. You should cache your image element first and then update its `src` on each iteration.

Here's a version that uses `setTimeout`.

```js
const images = [
  'https://dummyimage.com/200x200/ad62ad/000000',
  'https://dummyimage.com/200x200/61ab67/000000',
  'https://dummyimage.com/200x200/6170ab/000000'
];

const img = document.querySelector('img');

function carousel(count = 0) {
  count === 2 ? count = 0 : ++count;
  img.src = images[count];
  setTimeout(carousel, 1000, count);
}

carousel();
```

```html
<img />
```